# curl different result between old and new nginx versions

Tags: nginx

I have 2 servers has different version of nginx 1.4 and 1.6, when I run a curl command to check a live status of my site. I got 2 different response.

```
   on server with ngnix 1.4 I got  HTTP/1.1 200 OK
   on server with nginx 1.6 I got  HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
```

I have checked  /etc/nginx/nginx.conf I didn't see any difference. anyone have similar experiance or known bug?

Comment: Check again, there must be a difference.

Comment: thanks for response.I double check again but no diff. have you use version 1.6 and work for you?